# How to get Fping Result out of terminal

Tags: python, string, ping

I am using this command to get output:

```
command_fping = ["fping", 'wikipedia.org','-c 3']
p = subprocess.check_output(command_fping)
print("P is,",p)
```

Now what it shows on the terminal is this:

```
wikipedia.org : xmt/rcv/%loss = 3/3/0%, min/avg/max = 343/347/351
('P is,', 'wikipedia.org : [0], 96 bytes, 351 ms (351 avg, 0% loss)\nwikipedia.org : [1], 96 bytes, 349 ms (350 avg, 0% loss)\nwikipedia.org : [2], 96 bytes, 343 ms (347 avg, 0% loss)\n')
```

I need to access the first output line.

```
"wikipedia.org : xmt/rcv/%loss = 3/3/0%, min/avg/max = 343/347/351" <-- This line!
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as an argument to `check_output()`.  This is needed if your command writes to stderr in addition to stdout.  You may even want to try redirecting stdout to nowhere, if you only want the stderr output.

Comment: This gives invalid syntax.
I previously used stdout=subprocess.PIPE, but didnt work

Comment: Show me your syntax, I didn't propose anything invalid.

Comment: p = subprocess.check_output(command_fping,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

Comment: @UmairAhsan: that syntax is valid and working in Python.  I used "ls" as the command and it worked.  You are confusing the issue, there is no syntax error using my answer.  Please be more methodical.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X.  The same code would work on Linux.

Comment: Do you get this output in the same format as I have shown? (This is for Linux)